# Como uso uma variável de uma função em outra função - Python

Tags: python, flask

Estou tentando usar a variável `somarTotal` da função `tabelaVendas()` na minha função `dashboard()`. Alguém sabe como consigo fazer isso?

```
def tabelaVendas(somarTotal):

    somarTotal = 0

    consultaValorVenda = f"""SELECT dbo.FormataValor(Valor_Total,'.',',') from Venda where ID_Estabelecimento = 1"""
    listaVenda = cursor.execute(consultaValorVenda).fetchall()

    for dadosVenda in listaVenda:
        pegarValor = dadosVenda[0].replace(',','.')
        somarTotal = somarTotal+float(pegarValor)

    @app.route('/restaurante/dashboard/')
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html", nomeDono = nomeDono, somarTotal = somarTotal)
```

Answer (score -3):

Acho que você deveria fazer uma classe, não usar 2 funções,porque pela classe fica mais fácil, acessar os atributos dela própria. usando self e tals

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).